# using left join and where in another field of joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables users and work_orders.
Now I need to get work_orders results by filtering from users table field.

My following query did not return result.

```
SELECT `work_orders`.`id` as id, `work_orders`.`type` as type
     , `work_orders`.`title` as title, `work_orders`.`status` as status
     , `work_orders`.`publish_date` as publish_date
     , `work_orders`.`priority` as priority, `work_orders`.`assigned_to` as assigned_to
     , `work_orders`.`client_id` as client_id, `work_orders`.`due_date` as due_date 
  FROM (`work_orders`) 
  LEFT JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `work_orders`.`assigned_to` 
 WHERE `work_orders`.`status` != 'closed' 
   AND users.manager_id = '143' 
 ORDER BY `work_orders`.`id` DESC 
 LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Please take some time when writing your question to make it readable. You also may want to investigate aliases for tables; for instance, `select wo.id from work_orders as wo`. There's no need to use back-ticks on every column / table; only where you're using a reserved name.

Comment: remove the where clause and see what kind of hits you get.

Comment: Will check on that Ben from next time

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with query. You need to check that it should return data. e.g take the join out make sure it finds some orders.If itdoes put the join back, take the where out. Go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your WHERE clause filtering out all results?

Also, if you want to display work_orders that only pertain to certain users, change your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, or use EXISTS.

Try this...

```
SELECT field1, field2, ...
FROM work_orders
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM users 
    WHERE  users.id = work_orders.assigned_to 
       AND manager_id='143'
)
```

Comment: hello,
work_orders pretian to certain users but again users linked to manager_id which are users aswell. Now I need to filter work_orders by manager_id which is field in users table

Comment: So you're trying to get all the work orders under a certain manager.  Correct?

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelAlbert In the future use the code tags (curly braces on the editor) or indent code 4 spaces to make it more readable